# Error message on Maps "route not found"

Tags: google-maps

I have a Samsung S6 with Nougat 7.0.
Today, I can't navigate because I got the message "route not found".
This happened when I entered the destination with voice or by using my home address.

Then, I closed Maps and with "OK Google" I had my route.

Can someone please help me understand what happened and what can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Location Services switched on?

1. Settings
2. Location
3. Tap the Location switch
4. Make sure Mode is **High Accuracy**

https://www.bestusefultips.com/use-location-services-on-android-nougat-7-0-7-1/

Comment: ,thank you for your answer.I checked and Mode is on "High Accurancy".

Answer (score 0):

If you have  Location Services switched on and it still doesn't work, then I suggest you

- close the Google Maps app and re-launch it.
- sign out and sign back in to Google Maps with the same Google Account.
- clear App data:

  ```
  Open your device's Settings app (not the Google Settings app).
  Touch Apps.
  Select Google Maps in the list.
  Touch Clear data.
  ```
- uninstall and re-install the Google Maps app on your Android device.